# How to turn off/disable NFC programmataically?

Tags: android, nfc

How to write an application that turn off/disable NFC programmatically when I close my application or when my application is idle?

Comment: So why turn off NFC for the whole device? What about other apps which use NFC?

Answer (score 6):

If you really have to turn NFC off, use `NfcAdapter.disable();`.

However, you won't be able to use `disable()` API if your app is not system application which is build together with the platform.

Alternatively, you may show a notice (a dialog?) to the user and ask her if she wants to turn off the NFC. If user agrees, you can redirect her to global Settings UI using following `Intent`:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.NFC_SETTINGS"));
```

Comment: Can I turn off the NFC by set the  NFC to be STATE_OFF?